# How can I make the code for a problem use less memory to pass a test?

Tags: c++, memory-limit

I'm trying to solve a problem I found online, but I keep getting a memory error.

> You need to knit a scarf, for one ***.*** loop you need ***K*** millimeters of rope, and for ***/*** and ***|*** loops you need ***M*** and ***P*** millimeters accordingly. The goal is to find how many skeins with the length of ***H*** you need to finish the scarf.
>
> You input 2 variables in the first line: ***T***, ***R***.
>
> And in the second line you input: ***K***, ***M***, ***P*** and ***H***.
>
> Then you input ***T*** rows with ***R*** charachters in each.
>
> An example:
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
> 3 20
> 4 7 4 128
> |...|//./|..|||..|./
> ../....||/...||.|/||
> |||///||/.|||///|//.
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 3
> ```

The problem is being tested with [this file](https://imcs.dvfu.ru/cats/static/download/att/jabueHDcVd4sd6sUxp8PqpG6z7ITl1hL_input.txt).

How can I possibly make the code use less memory?

I tried using this code I wrote:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, r, k, m, p, h, a, ans, i, j;
    ans = 0;
    a = 0;
    cin >> t >> r;
    string knit[t];
    cin >> k >> m >> p >> h;
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> knit[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            if (knit[i][j] == '.') {
                a += k;
            }
            
            else if (knit[i][j] == '/') {
                a += m;
            }
            
            else {
                a += p;
            }
        }
    }
    while (a > 0) {
        a -= h;
        ans++;
    }
    cout << ans;
}
```

It works fine, but I keep getting a memory limit error.

Comment: This isn't even valid C++. That `string knit[t];` is some compiler giving you things not part of standard.

Comment: @TanveerBadar yeah, sorry, I'm a Python prgrammer and I don't know C++ well, I decided to use it to improve the speed. But how can you create an array of strings the other way?

Comment: You use a container from STL, like `vector<T>`, for allocating dynamic memory. This array is going on stack right now which has limited space available, hence your errors.

Answer (score 1):

I made the following improvements to your routine:

- There's now a need to create an array, we only need to allocate enough memory for 1 line.
- I over-allocate the memory needed, i.e. allow for 1024 characters in the line, but we will only process the input length
- I use a lookup table to map the stitch patterns to the number
- Finally, I use an integer math to compute the result needed - it implements roundup by pre adding (h - 1) before dividing by h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, r;
    cin >> t >> r;
    int k, m, p, h;
    cin >> k >> m >> p >> h;
    int table[256] = { };
    table['.'] = k;
    table['/'] = m;
    table['|'] = p;
    int x = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < t; i++) {
         char line[1024] = { };
         cin >> line;
         for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
             x += table[line[j]];
         }
    }
    cout << ((x + h - 1) / h) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's much better now. But I keep getting a runtime error. Do you know why it may occur?

Comment: @Nurgalinchik Is that a runtime error or a TimeLimitExceeded? If runtime please quote it.

Comment: @Nurgalinchik run the code through a debugger and step through it one line at a time until you find where its behavior differs from your expectations.

Comment: *now a need* or *now no need* or *not a need* or *now not a need*?